# Why did Napoleon IV die fighting in the British Army?

Tags: france

In 1879 in a war against the Zulu, [Napoleon IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Napol%C3%A9on,_Prince_Imperial), son of Napoleon III participating in the British army met his maker. The question is why wasn't he part of the French army?

After the 1870 war his father's empire was abolished, and Napoleon IV went first to Belgium then to England. There was talk of him marrying one of Queen Victoria's daughters and the latter was in favor of it.  He enrolled in some British military academy but I still find it odd that the British would let the most credible claimant to the French throne join their army.

Moreover, the Wiki article makes no mention of why he did not return to France. Perhaps he was banned from France but I doubt that. Still, I think it would have been better for his career to join the French army.  Maybe the French army was in shambles after their defeat in 1870, I don't know.

---

EDIT: Precisions by @totalmongot

The closing reason is unclear. The OP in the question does mention  points that are not "too basic" or answered by the single wikipedia article on Napoleon IV reading. Theses points are:

- Why did Napoleon IV not come back to France?
- Why did the British let him enter their army?

First point might find answers easily by googling, but not the second point. Because the second point is answered by the evolution of geopolitical context during 19th century, which is typically what an answer on SE could explain (since the OP is making the false assumption that Napoleon IV and Napoleon I had same feeling towards Britain).

Comment: Have a look at the French Wikipedia [Louis-Napoleon Bonaparte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Napol%C3%A9on_Bonaparte_(1856-1879)). It has more details and seems to largely answer your questions. On the title question, Louis-Napoleon says (via google translate) "When I have shown that I know how to risk my life for a country that is not mine, there will no longer be any doubt that I know how to risk it even better for my country.”

Comment: Why didn't I think of that, especially because I'm in the midst of studying French 24.7 right now.

Answer (score 4):

What might make you feel odd about these events is that you read them with a Napoleon I point of view and not Napoleon III's one.

For the first one, England was the opponent, as before for the Revolution and for the kings of France.
But under Napoleon III, England is, on the contrary, a reliable ally: Even if some rivalries still exist about colonial empires, and even if some British admirals are shaken when France launches new ships, overall, the two countries are Allies:

- They fought together the war of Crimea and they battled the Turkish fleet at Navarin
- They had the same behaviour during the American Civil war
- England feels united Prussia, with its industry, is an economic competitor, even more after the war of 1870
- They had common interests and intervene with their fleets in South America, during  the multiple wars that occurred there during the 19th century

So, France and United Kingdom were no longer opponents in the end of the 19th century. When Napoleon III had to abdicate, it was not as harsh as during the Revolution: the exile of Napoleon IV was a security for the French Republic but she did not try to kill him. So England was not annoying France by accepting him on her territory, and by enrolling in her army. On the other hand, it was not a good idea to make the son of the ex-Emperor fight in the French Army as an equal (in the Republican sense) of the other officers.

Comment: I've decided to leave this forum due to too many questions being closed.  No point in asking questions on a forum if each one gets closed for the most arbitrary and ridiculous of reasons.

Comment: @bobsmith76 I agree with you in the sense that too many questions are closed too fast on this forum

Comment: @totalMongot https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110

Comment: @Spencer The post you link gives situation examples that are very "naive" like "oh i love that game" and that has nothing to do with the situation we faced here, which is more like "You should not ask this question you ignorant of 19th century geopolitics"

Comment: @totalmongot, i was not reading this from a Napoleon I point of view, I wrote write in the question that there was talk of his N IV's marriage to one of Victoria's granddaughters.  Clearly, by writing that that shows I'm aware of the different relations between E and F in the years 1810 and 1879

Comment: @bobsmith76 Ok but then what is behind your question: "but I still find it odd that the British would let the most credible claimant to the French throne join their army"?

Comment: Well, if you were Britain would you let a foreign prince fight in your army, especially one from a country that you had been hostile towards since basically from the time the new nations were formed up until maybe the Crimean War?  Of course it's possible that he just wanted to gain experience but if he wanted experienced he could have fought in his own army.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_France#French_Third_Republic_(1870%E2%80%931940) France fought 16 wars between 1870 and 1914.  So probably the most likely motivation was espionage.

Comment: I think the debate of why Napoleon IV fought for Britain and not France, and why the British let him join up, is a great Q-and-A opportunity.  Maybe the OP could be re-worded to get it out of its closed status (which I believe is not deserved in this case).

Comment: @Smith I entirely agree
bobsmith ok I think I just misunderstood your previous comment